# A small OS that will boot under UEFI and wipe partitions on hard drives

Tags: hard-disk, operating-system

I'm looking for a small OS that will boot under UEFI and wipe partitions on hard drives; for example, a live boot CD of a Linux distribution. I tried so far Finnix, Nano Linux and Minimal Linux. None of these boot under UEFI mode.

It must boot under UEFI mode.

I need it to as quick as possible to boot and delete all partitions on all HDDs. I had it on FreeDOS but it doesn't boot under UEFI. I basically run a batch script with fdisk to clear all partitions. Since DOS doesn't work I thought linux will be able to.

It doesn't need to be a secure wipe of the hard drives: just to remove partitions, to wipe test Windows with test tools.

Comment: Ubuntu Server has Secure Boot support, fits on a CD, and boots pretty fast. Does that work for you?

Comment: If not for the UEFI requirement, I'd say dban.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that, you want to delete partitions manually.

I haven't tried EFI but **Paragon Backup & Recovery** has **bios** and **EFI** ISO's which you can create under Windows.

[image: RMB Wizard - Recovery Media Platform]

Comment: i want it automated, i can create script, but need light weight linux that can boot under UEFI